# Quirks Mode & IE8 Problem

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, quirks-mode

I have a very strange issue regarding only IE8 + Windows Vista, the error is very strange, I'll use some example names.

I have 2 pages, `page1.html` and `page2.html`, when opening both typing the address directly, there is no quirks mode.

When `page2.html` is opened via a `_blank` link (new window), it is displayed in Quirks Mode, this **ONLY** happens when the page is opened the way mentioned above.

Things I've tried

- Opening `page2.html` from different websites.
- Using `<!DOCTYPE html>` on `page1.html` and `page2.html`.

Things to note:

- The doctype on the pages is `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- There is **NO** whitespace / XML declaration above the DOCTYPE
- If the link is opened in a new tab or same tab, there is no problem.

This just baffles me, it works fine from IE8 on Windows7, and also works fine with IE6 on Windows XP.

**Update:** This doesn't happen on the test server, only on the production server, so is there anything server side that could affect this?

Also tried `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >` which I thought would force it to render as IE-8, but alas, it doesn't work.

Comment: are you sure what you're seeing is quirksmode, and not IE7-compatibility mode? (check what is shown in the dev tools window; press F12)

Comment: in that case, is your HTML valid? (have you checked with the W3C Validator?) Bad HTML code can cause IE to jump into quirks mode. Another possible thing that can trigger it is comments near your DOCTYPE.

Comment: There are a few errors, mostly non-issue stuff though

Comment: e.g. Unescaped characters, not recognising facebook opengraph stuff

Comment: the only other thing I can think of is browser settings. Possible that the specific browser has a setting which tells it to jump into quirksmode for a given site or zone (ie typically the local intranet zone). This would normally apply to compatibility mode rather than quirks mode, but worth checking, as I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Yeah, it's not browser settings sadly, it's a really strange problem and doubtful I will find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a rather straight forward problem, it was nothing to do with the page having bad code, it was an IE addon that caused it, thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Click Tools (right click the top of the browser window if you don't have a menu bar to enable it) -> Compatibility View Settings -> check if your intranet zone is set to display in compatibility view.